# Using Sub-process from a different project does not work

Tags: subprocess, project, jbpm, utilities

I want to create a project with different utilities process used in others projects (in example, process to send an email, process to send a document for a digital sign, etc).
But the problems cames when I want to use this process as subprocess in other procees implemented in different projects. I can select the utility process as called element in the re-usable subprocess in the origin process but in execution time don`t works and I have an error.

I can select process B (which is in different project, 2) as called element from sub-process symbol in the process A on Project 1, but during execution time when process B its called from process A , I get a following error for example : Application Subprocess:1] -- Could not find process Application-Process.application-process

If I put process B in Project 1 and process A calls the process B, in this case on a same project, it works fine.

Which tells me the way I call the subprocess works fine. But in differents projects don't works. Have no sense to replicate an reusable process in each project you want to use it. Any modification in this reusable process need to be done on each project.

Some other thread says all I need to do is include the process B's information in the pom file, but no luck for me.   Both projects are deployed and running on the respective container.

What I am mainly confused is when I click on the + icon for the subprocess it does open the process B.

Is there any workaround I can give it a try?